# C# true time for copying files from one folder to another folder

Tags: c#, time, stopwatch, copying

I wrote a script Task in c# where I copy files from one folder into another. The goal is to measure how long the copying process is taking from the first file until all files are copied.

Can I measure the true time, from the first file until the copying process is completed, reliably by using the Stopwatch?
Or simply, does the code continue during my copying method, or only after the whole copying process is competed and all files are in the new folder?

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

//Array for all Files
string[] allfiles;

//Source of all Files in: Pfad_Quelle
string quellpfad = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Pfad_Quelle"].Value;

//Read the name of all files in the source folder and Fill the Array "allfiles" 
allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(quellpfad, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();

int count = allfiles.Length;

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    string pfad_quelle = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Pfad_Quelle"].Value + allfiles[i - 1];
    string pfad_ziel = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Pfad_Ziel"].Value + allfiles[i - 1];

    try
    {
        File.Copy(@pfad_quelle, @pfad_ziel, true);                    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
ts.Milliseconds / 10);
MessageBox.Show("RunTime " + elapsedTime);


Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: Welcome. Your code will be executed sequentially, not concurrently. `MessageBox.Show("RunTime " + elapsedTime);` will show up as soon as all the files have been copied. Besides that, you're also including the execution time of `Directory.GetFiles`. If your really want the time it took to _copy_ the files, you might want to start your timer right before the loop and end it right after the loop. Oh, and the code will stop executing if an error occurs - until you've closed the message box (which may falsify your time while it's open).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure time spent to *copy* all the files, remove `stopWatch.Start();`, `stopWatch.Stop();` and
put them as close to `File.Copy` as you can:

```
...
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    string pfad_quelle = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Pfad_Quelle"].Value + allfiles[i - 1];
    string pfad_ziel = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Pfad_Ziel"].Value + allfiles[i - 1];

    try
    {
        try 
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            File.Copy(@pfad_quelle, @pfad_ziel, true);   
        }
        finally 
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }                  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
...
```